# What does 多一些 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm now chatting with someone from China, and she said the following:

> A: 你在北京工作吗？我三月去那里。
>
> I: 没有。我去北京市旅游的。我三月在意大利。
>
> A: 你在上海时间多一些吧。

What does the final sentence mean? I understand "if/when you are in Shanghai", but what does 多一些 mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 多 = many/ much/ a lot
- 多些 = more
- 一些 = some; a little
- 多一些 (more by some/ more by a little) = "little more " in English

Her full sentence without any omission would be:

"你在上海(的)时间(比你在意大利的时间)多一些吧?"
"Your time in Shanghai (compare to your time in Italy) is little more, right?"

It can translates to : "your time in Shanghai is little more (than your time in Italy), right?"

If she wrote 你在上海时间多些吧? Then the translation would be simply: "your time in Shanghai is more (than your time in Italy), right?

*吧 here is a final particle for softening the tone of a speech or indicating uncertainty. Without 吧 at the end, the sentence would sound like a hard fact statement. With 吧, the sentence sounds softer, more like a conversation, and leaves room for you to confirm or invalidate.

Example:

- "你在上海时间多一些。" -- "your time in Shanghai is little more"(plain statement)
- 你在上海时间多一些**吧**?"  -- "your time in Shanghai is little more, **right**?" ( softer tone, not presumptive, conversation like)

*If you don't use 'right', you could use 'heh?'*

> She mistakenly used a period instead of a question mark.  Even it is a rhetorical question, it still needs the question mark.
>
> Since it is not a real question, people sometimes omit the question mark. It may lead to confusion if there's not enough context to indicate it is  rhetorical.
>
> 你在上海时间多一些吧。 would be a suggestion or a command.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it but it is so difficult to come up with what is omitted in Mandarin. And what is the 吧 mean them?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is `?` unneeded here or is it just that she omitted it too?

Comment: Answer edited again.

Answer (score 2):

adj. + "一些" means "more adj." here. More examples are as follows:

```
"好一些"  better
"差一些"  worse
"在家待久一些"  stay home longer
```

Answer (score 0):

‘你在上海的时间多一些.’

means‘You have more time in Shanghai’

一般把‘吧’作为语气词或助词使用，用在句末.

‘吧’在不同情况下可以表示‘赞同，推测、命令、请求’等不同语气；用在句中表示停顿。

在这里，‘吧’表示推测（询问）。

Answer (score 0):

I think person A is Chinese.

A:你在北京工作吗？我三月去那里。
A: Are you work on Beijing? I have been to Beijing on March!

I: 没有。我去北京市旅游的。我三月在意大利。
I: No!I went to Beijing to travel!I am in Italy in March!

OK!The problem is come!

Because person A is only listening "I went to Beijing to travel!" in his mind!

A: 你在上海时间多一些吧。(。->?)(PS:他根本是個問句)
The total word is
A: If you travel to Beijing,you spend the time in the Shanghai is more then Beijing!Is right?

Answer (score 0):

From reading it, I believe it means: "(Please, I beg you to) Be in Shanghai (just, for only) some more time!" It's a command.

Comment: This is what I thought first; that's why I was confused and posted a question here.